# Is this a valid edit?

Tags: discussion

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43449416/nsunderlyingerror-0x17405d7c0-error-domain-kcferrordomaincfnetwork-code-1002

This question was edited recently with some changes to fix the image description. But the other grammatical mistakes (which are pretty apparent) and wording of the question were not fixed.

As per guidelines, edits should be as complete as possible (try to make the post significantly better when you edit, correcting all problems that you observe).

Should incremental edits like these be allowed? Or am I missing some key point here?

Comment: We ask **suggested** edits to fix all issues in a post, because those edits have to go through review. We want to make the most efficient use of our reviewers so edits should be reasonably complete. That specific edit was made by someone with > 2k rep, so no review was needed.

Comment: So can I call it an irresponsible edit?

Comment: You can call it anything you want in private. On the site, just suggest a better edit? Perhaps the post isn't worth the extra time to that editor right now.

Comment: I would indeed suggest a better edit. Thank you.

Comment: Safe your time. This question is currently bad and should be closed (for example as "why isn't this code working). Fixing the grammar won't change that and OP is supposed to add the missing content to make the question on-topic and it is very likely that (s)he will add more grammar issues. So wait until the quesiton _really_ worth to be edited by you.

Answer (score 3):

It is valid edit for someone with *full editing privileges*, but not enough for edit that would go through review queue.

Note that as question currently stands it is not possible for anyone but author to provide enough information inline to make question self-contained and complete - so it would be inadvisable to make edit that would go through review queue as all changes would be essentially minor. Even if accepted such edit is likely be gone soon when question is deleted by Roomba due to low quality - so spending effort on making good complete edit would be wasted.

I do such edits from time to time when I hope author provided some code in the post but it is not visible due to formatting (happen usually in JavaScript/HTML tags, but people are very "creative" when writing question). The only way to confirm it is to click "edit" to see raw markup and at that point a single character edit to show image is essentially free.

Answer (score 1):

That was a harmful edit. All the editor did was inline an image that had been linked by the asker. The image was a screenshot of text - if anything, they should have transcribed the relevant portion of the text into the question. Instead, they bumped a terrible question to the homepage and did missed the opportunity to teach the asker about our expectations for good questions (i.e. posting MVCEs with textual information as plain text - not in an image).

Comment: Sure, it wasn't very helpful; but I'm not sure it was harmful. Inlining an image means it's less likely to break if the image later disappears from the Internet.

Comment: @NathanArthur The edit didn't change where the image was hosted, it just changed it from a link format to an image format.  You can see from the markdown diff that the edit is a single character change, adding `!` in front of the link.

Comment: My bad. Should have actually looked at the diff before commenting. :)